# PHP file_exists is lying to me (saying file exists but it doesnt)

Tags: php

Doing this:

```
php -r 'unlink("path"); clearstatcache(); echo file_exists("path");'
```

Where path is a full absolute path to a file on my linux machine.  Command is returning '`1`' even though the file is clearly not there.  You can run this command a million times, it will always tell you the file is there.

Running:

```
ls path
```

Tells you there's no such file.

what gives?

Update:
I know about clearstatcache().  That does not help in this case.  Additionally, I'm running this with the cli.  Nothing changes from run to run.  I'm also on a 64-bit VM running ubuntu 11.10.

Path is just a path on the filesystem: /var/www/yo.txt.  www is a nfs shared mount, not sure if that has something to do with it.  The file was removed from a remote machine, but the local machine seems to know its not there.  'ls' on the directory shows no files, and ls with the path claims says that the file is not there.  The file was just a few kb, nothing huge.

Comment: The documentation mentions something about erratic behavior on 32bit systems for larger files (>2GB). Could this possibly be what you are seeing?

Comment: *"what gives?"* - reading the manual *might* help. http://php.net/clearstatcache

Comment: @hakre, did **you** keep reading? `unlink()` *clears the cache automatically*.

Comment: See the first comment on this documentation page -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php

Comment: I could also imagine that this needs poking the file-system in some circumstances. However check with `ls` if you do not trust the `file_exists` any longer.

Comment: Tell us more about *path*? Is it a local file? How was it created? What are it's permissions?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: I would in any case try if `clearstatchace` helps. Just to be on the safe side in case this differs from documented behavior.

Comment: @hakre, without knowing more about *path*, I agree. Was only pointing out that under *normal* circumstances, `clearstatcache()` should not be needed. Which I verified.

Comment: What does `var_dump(file_get_contents("path"));` output ??

Answer (score 2):

PHP is telling the truth it knows. The culprit is the NFS attribute cache. You can call `clearstatcache` all day long, to no effect: NFS is in charge.

I explored what's happening [in another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41724398/2908724), but the short answer is this: tune your NFS mount options to give you faster answers (try [`noac`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/nfs)) or use [`opendir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) and [`closedir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.closedir.php) to invalidate the NFS cache then call `clearstatcache()`, like:

```
php -r 'unlink("path"); $d = dirname("path"); opendir($d); closedir($d); clearstatcache(); echo file_exists("path");'
```